# jquery easyui not charge the .js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I use the easyui table for administration users, I added correctly all scripts, but something come into conflict with `jquery.easyui.min.js`  I tried to eliminate all js for see if is working but, its not working, so is not js conflict.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

may be in conflict with any function?

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>cPanel - Home </title>
    <link href="_template/css/main.css?v=1395844208" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="_template/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://swapes.com/cPanel/_template/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://swapes.com/cPanel/_template/js/jquery-easyui-1.3.2/easyloader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_template/css/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_template/css/icon.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="_template/css/cssgraphbox.css?v=1395844208" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<style>.logged { display:none; }</style><script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){$('#sidebar').load('_core/after-login.php?what=sidebar&rand='+Math.random());  $('#content-menu').load('_core/after-login.php?what=content-menu&rand='+Math.random());
     });     
</script><style>.nologged { display:none }</style><style>.logged { display:block; }</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.sidebar-item-content').live('click',function() {
            var url = $(this).attr('data');
            var hash = url.split(".");
            window.location.hash = hash[0]; 
            $('.sidebar-item-content').css("padding-left","0px");
            $(this).css("padding-left","10px");
            $("#content").fadeOut(300).html("<center><img src='http://swapes.com/_template/images/load.gif'></center>");
            $("#content").load("_core/"+url+"?rand="+Math.random());
            $("#content").delay(300).fadeIn(300);
            $(this).parent().find(".sidebar-load").fadeIn(300).delay(500).fadeOut(300);
    });


$('#settings').live('click',function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('data');
        var hash = url.split(".");
        window.location.hash = hash[0]; 
        $("#content").fadeOut(300);
        $("#content").load("_core/"+url+"?rand="+Math.random());
        $("#content").delay(300).fadeIn(300);

    });

    $('.FAQ').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $item = $(this).find('div');

        $item.slideToggle('fast');
    });
});


var targetWin;
var user= "2";
function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, id, name, w, h , what) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
    targetWin = window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
                $("#feedback").html('Verifying... <img src="_template/images/load.gif" height="16px">');
                $("#content-title #title").fadeOut(10);
                $("#feedback").delay(100).fadeIn(10);
    var watchClose = setInterval(function() {
        if (targetWin.closed) {
            clearTimeout(watchClose);
            do_click(id, user,what,"click");
        }
    }, 2000);
} 





function daily(type) {
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "_core/do.php",
        cache: false,
        data: "what=daily&type="+type,
        success: function(msg){
                $('#jq-feedback').html(msg);
        }

    });
}

function contact()
{
var name = document.getElementById('contact_name').value;
var email = document.getElementById('contact_email').value;
var msg = document.getElementById('contact_message').value;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_core/do.php?what=contact",
cache: false,
        data: "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&msg="+msg,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#jq-feedback").html(msg);
        }


    });

}

function sendticket()
{
var tsubject = document.getElementById('ticket_subject').value;
var tmessage = document.getElementById('ticket_message').value;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_core/do.php?what=sendticket",
cache: false,
        data: "tsubject="+tsubject+"&tmessage="+tmessage,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#jq-feedback").html(msg);
        }


    });

}

function addbanner()
{
var tperiod = document.getElementById('packk_period').value;
var tlink = document.getElementById('banner_link').value;
var ttitle = document.getElementById('banner_title').value;
var frame=document.getElementById("uploadf");
if(frame.contentDocument.getElementById('imagename'))
var tname=frame.contentDocument.getElementById('imagename').src;
else
var tname="";
var price = tperiod*500;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_core/do.php?what=addbanner",
cache: false,
        data: "price="+price+"&link="+tlink+"&title="+ttitle+"&name="+tname,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#jq-feedback").html(msg);
        }


    });

}
function paydays(id)
{
var tperiod = document.getElementById('packk_period').value;
var price = tperiod*500;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_core/do.php?what=paydays",
cache: false,
        data: "price="+price+"&id="+id,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#jq-feedback").html(msg);
        }


    });

}



   </script>
   <script src="_template/js/alert.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (top !== self) top.location.href = self.location.href;
</script>


</head>
<body>

<span id="jq-feedback"></span>
        <div id="top">
            <div id="top_bar">
<span class="nologged" id="login_boxs">         
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" style="width:100px;background-image: url(_template/images/nume.png);background-position: 5px 5px; background-repeat: no-repeat;padding-left: 22px;" name="login" id="login" >
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" style="width:100px;background-image: url(_template/images/parola.png);background-position: 5px 5px; background-repeat: no-repeat;padding-left: 22px;" name="pass" id="pass">
<span style="line-height:26px"><input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" style="width:100px;margin: 0 0px 0 0px;" onclick="$(this).fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn();login()"></span>
</span>
<span class="nologged" id="forgot_password" style="display:none">           
<input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" style="width:130px;background-image: url(_template/images/email.png);background-position: 5px 5px; background-repeat: no-repeat;padding-left: 22px;" name="f_email" id="f_email">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Reset password" style="width:130px;margin: 0 0px 0 0px;" onclick="$(this).fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn();forgot_password_send()">
</span>
<span style="float:right;position:relative;background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;">
<table><tr><td class="logged">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="myTickets" onclick="$('#content').load('_plugins/ticket/mytickets.php'); window.location.hash = 'myTickets';" class="button" style="width:120px;text-align:center">Messages</a></td><td><div class="logged" id="tbulina" >
0</div></td><td class="logged">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#content').load('_core/alerts.php?rand='+Math.random()); window.location.hash = 'alerts';" class="button" style="width:60px;text-align:center">Alerts</a></td><td><div id="bulina" class="logged">
3</div></td>
<td>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="myTickets" onclick="$('#content').load('_plugins/ticket/mytickets.php'); window.location.hash = 'myTickets';" class="button" style="width:120px;text-align:center">Tickets</a></td><td><div class="logged" id="tbulina" >
0</td><td class="logged">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" style="width:100px;text-align:center" id="tour">View Website</a>
</td></tr></table>
</span><br clear="all"> 
        </div>  

        <div id="logo_ads">
                    <img src="_template/images/new.png" id="logo"/>
            <div id="subheader">cPanel Management & Site Security</div>


                <div class="msg-loading mws-inset">
<table><tr><td class="">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" style="width:100px;height:70px;text-align:center;line-height: 17px;" id="tour"></br>Credits Income</br>
<span style="float:center;color: #0F3968;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px">0.00 $<br></span> </a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" style="width:100px;height:70px;text-align:center;line-height: 17px;" id="tour"></br>Premium Income</br>
<span style="float:center;color: #0F3968;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px">828.60 $<br></span> </a> 
</td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" style="width:100px;height:70px;text-align:center;line-height: 17px;" id="tour"></br>Total Income</br>
<span style="float:center;color: #0F3968;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px">2144.10 $<br></span> </a> 

</td></tr></table>
</div>

            </span>

        </div>

<!-- end heder -->  
    <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="sidebar">



    </div>  
    <div id="pre-content" style="min-height:600px">
        <div id="content-menu">
                    </div>
        <div id="content">

<h1><span>Dashboard</span></h1></br>
<table id="nested"  cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr><th width="80px">Online Members</th><th width="110px">Premium Members</th><th width="165px">Banned Members</th><th width="90px">Registered Today</th><th align="right" width="60px">Total Members</th></tr></div>
<tbody>


<td><span style="color: #0F3968;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px">
5 Users </span></td>
<td><span style="color: #0F3968;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px">209</span></td>
<td><span style="color: #9F1915;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px"></span></td>
<td><span style="color: #0F3968;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px">....</span></td>
<td><span style="color: #0F3968;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px"></span></td>
</tbody>
</table>
</table>
<table>
</br>
                           <!-- Statistics example with Flot plugin -->
                           <table id="nested"  cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style="border-collapse:collapse;">

                            <tr><th width="90px">Website Statistics</th></tr>
            </table>
                           <table id="nested"  cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style="border-collapse:collapse;">

                            <div class="body-con">
                                <div class="stats" style="height:300px"></div>
                            </div>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span style="color: #0F3968;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px">0 </span>Total Visits</td>
                                        <td><span style="color: #0F3968;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px">0 </span>Unique Visits</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                            <!-- END Statistics example with Flot plugin -->







 <!-- Include Javascript -->

        <script>            
        function randNum() {
            return (Math.floor( Math.random()* (1+40-20) ) ) + 20;
        }
        var chartColours = ['#88bbc8', '#ed7a53', '#9FC569', '#bbdce3', '#9a3b1b', '#5a8022', '#2c7282'];

            $(function(){
              //some data
        var d1 = [[1, 310],[2, 320],[3, 326],[4, 268],[5, 279],[6, 279],[7, 315],[8, 336],[9, 303],[10, 347],[11, 355],[12, 322],[13, 364],[14, 333],[15, 341],[16, 266],[17, 289],[18, 318],[19, 336],[20, 265],[21, 258],[22, 326],[23, 329],[24, 299],[25, 565],[26, 344]];

        var d2 = [[1, 167],[2, 176],[3, 191],[4, 179],[5, 190],[6, 183],[7, 181],[8, 219],[9, 191],[10, 243],[11, 252],[12, 212],[13, 228],[14, 218],[15, 200],[16, 165],[17, 205],[18, 211],[19, 188],[20, 187],[21, 185],[22, 190],[23, 204],[24, 196],[25, 184],[26, 114]];
        //define placeholder class
        var placeholder = $(".stats");
        //graph options
        var options = {
                grid: {
                    show: true,
                    aboveData: true,
                    color: "#3f3f3f" ,
                    labelMargin: 5,
                    axisMargin: 0, 
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    borderColor:null,
                    minBorderMargin: 5 ,
                    clickable: true, 
                    hoverable: true,
                    autoHighlight: true,
                    mouseActiveRadius: 20
                },
                series: {
                    grow: {active:false},
                    lines: {
                        show: true,
                        fill: true,
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        steps: false
                        },
                    points: {show:false}
                },
                legend: { position: "se", show:false },
                yaxis: { min: 0 },
                xaxis: {ticks:11, tickDecimals: 0, min: 1, max: 31},
                colors: chartColours,
                shadowSize:1,
                tooltip: true, //activate tooltip
                tooltipOpts: {
                    content: "%s : %y.0",
                    shifts: {
                        x: -30,
                        y: -50
                    }
                }
            };   

            $.plot(placeholder, [ 

                {
                    label: "Visits", 
                    data: d1,
                    lines: {fillColor: "#f2f7f9"},
                    points: {fillColor: "#88bbc8"}
                }, 
                {   
                    label: "Unique Visits", 
                    data: d2,
                    lines: {fillColor: "#fff8f2"},
                    points: {fillColor: "#ed7a53"}
                } 

            ], options);

    });  
        </script>   </div>


<div  class='logged' id="under-content">
<div id="sub-content-box">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" style="width:208px;height:32px;text-align:center;line-height: 11px;" id="tour"></br>Create New Coupon</a>
<div style="background: #FFF6BF;color: #514721;border-color: #FFD324;padding: 5px 10px;margin: 0 0 5px;border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;">Once you create a coupon, the name and amount cannot be changed. You can only use a name once. <br/><a href="javascript: void(0)"></a></div>
</div>
<div id="sub-content-box">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" style="width:208px;height:32px;text-align:center;line-height: 11px;" id="tour"></br>Technical Support</a>
<div style="background: #FFF6BF;color: #514721;border-color: #FFD324;padding: 5px 10px;margin: 0 0 5px;border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;">Collaborate Technical Support (Available 24 Hours / Day - 7 Days / Week) <br/><a href="javascript: void(0)"></a></div>
</div>
<div id="sub-content-box">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" style="width:208px;height:32px;text-align:center;line-height: 11px;" id="tour"></br>Updates</a>
<div style="background: #FFF6BF;color: #514721;border-color: #FFD324;padding: 5px 10px;margin: 0 0 5px;border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;"><h6>16/05/2011 15:00</h6>New update is available for comments plugin! <br/><a href="javascript: void(0)">Update now</a></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" style="width:208px;height:102px;text-align:center;line-height: 21px;" id="tour"></br>
<div style="font-size:11px;margin:3px 15px"><b>Your Version:</b> <strong style="color:green"></strong></span></div>
<div style="font-size:11px;margin:2px 15px"><b>Latest Version:</b> <strong style="color:blue"></strong></span></div>
</a>
</div>


    </div>  <div id="sub-content">
    <a href="">Terms and Conditions</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#content').load('_core/after-login.php?what=politcy&rand='+Math.random()); window.location.hash = 'politcy';">Privacy Politcy</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#content').load('_core/after-login.php?what=contact&rand='+Math.random()); window.location.hash = 'contact';">Contact Us</a> <a href="">

    </a><a href="#" style="float:right">Swapes.com - All rights reserved (c) 2014 </a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much in anticipated!

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Can not anyone help me? I feel like going crazy, I can not find the problem :(

Comment: there is much too much going on in your code I do not know where to start, try to isolate the problem maybe make a testcase on jsbin

Comment: @Steeve17 I don't find the problem :(

Comment: me too... but is an big problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Bulina qkemi, try using Jquery Datatables
https://www.datatables.net/